# Automate parallel uploading local file when upload other

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I trying to code a chrome extension. Task:
On my page I have two *input type=file* fields. When start uploading file from one input (by choosing file from my disk and clicking upload button), I need the other file with the same name, but other folder adding to another input and start uploading too (or post it, for example). 
My problem at this moment is blocking get local file by chrome extension to operate with it.

```
function readFile(_path, _cb){
  let txt = '';
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
                console.log(txt)
            }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", _path, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
      readFile('file://F:/my-file.txt', function(_res){
        console.log(_res);
      });
  });
}
```

I tried to allow access by different conditions in chrome starting (such as --disable-web-security and -–allow-file-access-from-files), but it doesn't work. The answer is `file:///F:/my-file.txt net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Stocksy Uploader",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Parallel upload original video files",
  "permissions": ["declarativeContent","storage",{"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]},"activeTab","file:///"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": ["https://testingdomain/*"],
     "js": ["contents.js"]
   }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

Comment: Looks like a typo: there should be three `///` in a file URL, not two.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried this variant too, the same error

Comment: Is this inside a content script? Modern Chrome forbids cross-origin requests there. Do it in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm replace xmlhttprequest function to background?